# Second Column on First Page Going Off the Page

Tags: margins, templates, two-column

I am trying to use the PNAS template for an assignment. Using some other posts on here I've painfully managed to get the formatting to work everywhere apart from the first page. I want a two column document, and this is working on all pages apart from the first. On the first page, the first column is fine, but then the second column starts very far from the center and goes off the page:
[image]

I believe this is to do with the "Significance Statement" float that is found on the first page.

My main tex file looks like:

```
\documentclass[9pt,twocolumn,twoside,lineno]{pnas-new}
\templatetype{pnasresearcharticle}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\title{Template for preparing your research report submission to PNAS using Overleaf}
\author[a,c,1]{Author One}
\author[b,1,2]{Author Two} 
\author[a]{Author Three}

\affil[a]{Affiliation One}
\affil[b]{Affiliation Two}
\affil[c]{Affiliation Three}
\leadauthor{Lead author last name} 

\significancestatement{Authors must submit a 120-word maximum statement about the
significance of their research paper written at a level understandable to an undergraduate
educated scientist outside their field of speciality. The primary goal of the Significance
Statement is to explain the relevance of the work in broad context to a broad readership.
The Significance Statement appears in the paper itself and is required for all research papers.}

\begin{abstract}
Please provide an abstract of no more than 250 words in a single paragraph. Abstracts should
explain to the general reader the major contributions of the article. References in the
abstract must be cited in full within the abstract itself and cited in the text.
\end{abstract}
\dates{This manuscript was compiled on \today}
\doi{\url{www.pnas.org/cgi/doi/10.1073/pnas.XXXXXXXXXX}}


\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firststyle}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{shortarticle}}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{singlecolumn}}{\abscontentformatted}{\abscontent}}{}

\firstpage{1}[46]
\dropcap{T}his PNAS journal template is provided to help you write your work in the correct
journal format.  Instructions for use are provided below. \blindtext[9] 

\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

The pnas .sty file looks like:

```
%%% PNAS two column research article  style file
%%% For use with pnas-new.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{pnasresearcharticle}[2018/05/06 v1.3 PNAS two column research article style]

%% Set whether the abstract is set into the first column
\setboolean{shortarticle}{true}
% true = set into first column
% false = spans page width

%% Set colors
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{130,0,0} % color

%% Set up the first page footnote/fact box here
\RequirePackage{float}
\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{sigstatement}{bp!}{sst}

\additionalelement{%
\afterpage{\begin{flushleft}\begin{sigstatement}
\sffamily
\mdfdefinestyle{pnassigstyle}{backgroundcolor=pnasblueback,linecolor=pnasblueback,fontcolor=pnasbluetext,innertopmargin=9.3pt,innerrightmargin=11.4pt,innerbottommargin=12pt,innerleftmargin=11.4pt,linewidth=0pt,userdefinedwidth=\columnwidth}
\@ifundefined{@significancestatement}{}{%   
    \begin{mdframed}[style=pnassigstyle]%
    \section*{Significance Statement}%
    \textcolor{black}\@significancestatement
    \end{mdframed}}
\end{sigstatement}

\end{flushleft}
}
}

\endinput
```

There is also a .cls file but its quite long and I'm not sure that its relevant. I've added a bit of it below relating to the float in case it helps:

```
%% For the Significance Statement & footnote on the first page
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf,ifxetex}
\ifpdf\else
  \ifxetex\else
    \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\fi\fi
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
```

Thanks

Edit: The template can be found at https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-preparing-your-research-report-submission-to-pnas-using-overleaf-2023/whbdryzwztnd

Comment: When you are using a non standard document class, please remember to state where to get that template.

Comment: @daleif sorry just added that now!

Comment: Where exactly are you compiling this? I do not get any issues if I use that template on Overleaf and replace the contents with your MWE.

Comment: @daleif I am just compiling on overleaf. Are you able to get text in the second column of the first page that is well formatted?

Comment: `\afterpage` is explicitly not supported in a two column class so `\afterpage{\begin{flushleft}\begin{sigstatement}` can not possibly work.

Comment: @AlexandreBloch I only took your code from the example you gave, and compile it and observed that the result does not match your image.

Comment: the overleaf texmplate and the code you posted do not use any file called pnas.sty